# updating OpenGL based on system time

Tags: opengl

Using OpenGL for a network based game, I would like to make the Display.sync class start at a specific time.  For instance, if the game is started at 5:30 PM at 49.5635 seconds, I would like the program to wait until it is 5:30 at 50 seconds until starting the update loop.  This way I can send a ping every second on the second.  Is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is quite vague - but, to answer generally: trying to synchronize games based on wall-clock time is not possible in practice (see a relevant discussion of approximation techniques in this question -https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32118/how-to-synchronize-clocks-in-multiplayer-game).